# Getting junk values when reading a string from File

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio

I am trying to read some data from a text file in my c program but getting junk values.

Below is the input format in the file

```
3442
Tack Hammer
9
3.550000
ABC317
```

Here is my code to read this file data

```
char name[100];
int product_code;

fscanf(fin, "%d", &x[i].product_code); //taking id from file is fine
printf("\n%d\n",x[i].product_code); // works correctly

fscanf(fin,"%[^\n]",name);
printf("Data from file:\n%s",name);  // it displays junk values
```

Here is the output preview

[image]
can someone correct me please. thank you

Answer (score 4):

Lets go through the code.

```
char name[100];
```

creates a `char` array 100 bytes long. It is uninitialized and contains "garbage".

```
fscanf(fin, "%d", &x[i].product_code);
```

scans `3442` from `fin`.

```
printf("\n%d\n",x[i].product_code);
```

prints a newline character,the number scanned by the above `fscanf`, and a newline character. The line

```
fscanf(fin,"%[^\n]",name);
```

is what is causing the problem. The next character to be read is `\n`, a newline character. **`%[^\n]` will fail if the next character is a `\n`**. Thus, the `fscanf` fails and returns zero.

```
printf("Data from file:\n%s",name);
```

prints `Data from file`,a newline character and the "garbage" that `name` contains.

---

How to fix this?

Use a `getc(fin);` just after the first `fscanf` to read and discard the `\n` character.

Comment: sorry but i did not understood the solution. i tried printf("Data from file:\n%s",name); but did not worked. can you elaborate it please. thanks

Comment: Add `getc(fin)` just after the first `fscanf`

Answer (score 2):

the first call to fscanf() does not consume the newline

The second call to fscanf() fails (a very good reason to always check the returned value from any of the scanf family of functions.)

In the second call to fscanf(), inserting a ' ' (space) as the first character of the format string will cause any white space to be skipped.  (an newline is white space)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in:

```
fscanf(fin,"%[^\n]",name);
```

Because your are recieving `\n`; `fscanf` will fail. The variable `name`will not be filled so it contain garbage. You need to read one more character to avoid `\n`and continue.

Answer (score -2):

I believe it's because you didn't initialize `name`.

`char name[100] = { 0 };`

Comment: Do you disagree that he is (trying to) initialize it by performing his call to `fscanf(fin,"%[^\n]",name);`? If indeed there is a problem with how he is calling `fscanf()` here (or failing to examine its results for error handling), explicit initialization as you request would not solve the problem. It would, at best, hide the "strange characters" and replace them with output that is still not what he expects.